# Return list<Data> of an async function once in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a function that returns a list of names in an autocomplete list and gets the data from a webservice:

```
public async Task<SelectResponse> AutoSearchService(string filter)
   {
        SelectResponse ResponseData = new SelectResponse();
        var Url = string.Format("{0}{1}", "http://url&", filter);
        var Client = new HttpClient();
        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url.ToString());
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        var ResponseMessage = await Client.GetAsync(Url.ToString());
        if (ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ResponseData = await ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<SelectResponse>();
        }
        return ResponseData;
    }
```

And this is the AutoCompleteSearch:

```
private async Task<List<Autocomplete>> _GetSchool(string query)
    {
        var response = await AutoSearchService("");
        List<STVDPLMRECORDSELECT> searchFilter = response.SelectResult;
        List<Autocomplete> secondarySchools = new List<Autocomplete>();
        try
        {
            var results = (from s in searchFilter
                           where (s.STVDPLM_DESC).StartsWith(query)
                           select s).Take(10).ToList();
            foreach (var r in results)
            {
                // create objects
                Autocomplete schools = new Autocomplete();
                int i = 0;
                schools.Name =r.STVDPLM_DESC;
                schools.Id = i++ ;
                secondarySchools.Add(schools);
            }

        }
        catch (EntityCommandExecutionException eceex)
        {
            if (eceex.InnerException != null)
            {
                throw eceex.InnerException;
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return secondarySchools;
    }
```

It takes a long time to get the autocomplete list after each typing of any character so that I need to read this async webservice list just once time after run the controller to make it like a static list. 
Please any help to solve this problem.

Comment: You can try to cache the result from AutoSearchService if it is static data or maybe store in session if it is user specific at the very start just to avoid multiple calls each time

Comment: @R Jain Hi, Thanks for your reply.
please can you provide me with a little codes ?

Comment: 1) Ideally you do not want to hit the DB with each character typed. You want a delay (maybe 1/2 second) after the last keystroke finished and then hit the server for a list. In the meantime if typing resumes cancel the request and submit another after 1/2 second. 2) You could cache results 3) You can also tune the performance on the server, maybe a slow DB call is adding to the lag.